# How do I get the average 'rate' from my below MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

I have a mysql table with this structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `item_rate` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`item` int(11) NOT NULL,
`ip` int(32) NOT NULL,
`rate` int(1) NOT NULL,
`date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
KEY `item` (`item`),
CONSTRAINT `item_rate_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`item`) REFERENCES `items` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

I need to get this calculated information from this table:

here 'rate' may be 1,2,3,4 or 5
so I need to select every 'item'
and with this 'item'
calculate

```
if rate = 5
5 * COUNT(id)
if rate = 4
4 * COUNT(id)
```

and so on...

Example:

On item 1 I have

```
rate 5 count 100
rate 4 count 311
rate 3 count 188
rate 2 count 83
rate 1 count 10
```

select must calculate like this

```
(5 * 100 + 4 * 311 + 3 * 188 + 2 * 83 + 1 * 10) / 692(sum of counts) = 3.58
```

then round this 3.58
and return info like this

```
item count
1    3
2    4
3    5
4    3
5    5
```

How can I do this with 1 query?

P.S. I`m using mysql db

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT item, FLOOR(SUM(rate * ratecount) / SUM(ratecount)) AS cnt
FROM (SELECT item, rate, COUNT(id) ratecount
      FROM item_rate 
      GROUP BY item, rate
     ) AS A
GROUP BY item;
```

To fetch ip related details check below query:

```
SELECT item, FLOOR(SUM(rate * ratecount) / SUM(ratecount)) AS cnt, 
       (CASE WHEN SUM(ipExists) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ipExists
FROM (SELECT item, rate, COUNT(id) ratecount, 
             SUM(CASE WHEN ip > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ipExists
      FROM item_rate 
      GROUP BY item, rate
     ) AS A
GROUP BY item;
```

Comment: Error Code: 1630
FUNCTION vgnjhcbb_db.SUM does not exist. Check the 'Function Name Parsing and Resolution' section in the Reference Manual

Comment: @maiabardavelidze Check my updated answer. By mistake I had put a space in SUM function. You can check now,

Comment: also can I get ip column? if ip exists then return 1 if not 0
ip is unique for every item
so if example in item 1 list exists my ip
it must return 1
if not 0...
how can I do this???

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you simply want the average rating for an item.  This is most easily written as:

```
select item, avg(rate)
from item_rate
group by item;
```

If you want this to two decimal places, cast as a `decimal` or use `format()`:

```
select item, cast(avg(rate) as decimal(8, 2)) as avg_rate
from item_rate
group by item;
```

Answer (score 0):

In TSQL(MSSQL) i would use something like this:

```
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @total INT
DECLARE @number INT
SET @total = 0 
SET @number = 0
SET @i = 1  

WHILE (@i < 6)
BEGIN
SET @number = @number + (SELECT mt.countNumber FROM @MyTable mt WHERE mt.rate = @i) * @i
SET @total = @total + (SELECT mt.countNumber FROM @MyTable mt WHERE mt.rate = @i)
SET @i = @i+1
END

SELECT CAST(CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),@number)/CONVERT(DECIMAL(10,3),@total) AS DECIMAL(10,3))
```

Output is then: 3.590

Comment: I know thats why i wrote that on the start :)